# Using WebClient get only a table

Tags: c#, webclient

So I've been trying to teach my self C#, and a lot on here has been really helpful.  I've finished some of the basics and now I'm trying to work with WebClient and HtmlAgilityPack.  So when looking for a site to play around with data I came to the NWS hourly forecast (Boston chosen as random city): [forecast in boston](http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?w0=t&w1=td&w2=wc&w3=sfcwind&w3u=1&w4=sky&w5=pop&w6=rh&w7=thunder&w8=rain&w9=snow&w10=fzg&w11=sleet&AheadHour=48&&FcstType=digital&textField1=42.54688&textField2=-72.78013&site=all&unit=0&dd=0&bw=0&BackDay.x=61&BackDay.y=10&BackDay=0)

Is there a way to only grab the table?  Right now I'm getting the whole site, and it seems like it would be easier to play with if I only got the table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `WebClient` won't do it.

You might give a try to [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com)

> This is an agile HTML parser that builds a read/write DOM and supports
>   plain XPATH or XSLT (you actually don't HAVE to understand XPATH nor
>   XSLT to use it, don't worry...). It is a .NET code library that allows
>   you to parse "out of the web" HTML files. The parser is very tolerant
>   with "real world" malformed HTML. The object model is very similar to
>   what proposes System.Xml, but for HTML documents (or streams).

Comment: I figured as much, I just wanted to be sure.  I've been playing around with HTML Agility Pack more.  It's much easier to use than I thought it would be.